# Merge duplicate cells of a column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

---

### My Current excel looks like:

```
  ----------------
  |  Type |  Val |
  |--------------|
  |  A    |  1   |
  |--------------|     
  |  A    |  2   |     
  |--------------|
  |  B    |  3   |
  |--------------|     
  |  B    |  4   |     
  |--------------|     
  |  B    |  5   |
  |--------------|
  |  C    |  6   |
```

### ----------------

### This is the required excel:

```
  ----------------------
  |  Type |  Val | Sum |
  |--------------------|
  |  A    |  1   | 3   |
  |       |------|     |
  |       |  2   |     |
  |--------------------|
  |  B    |  3   | 12  |
  |       |------|     |
  |       |  4   |     |
  |       |------|     |
  |       |  5   |     |
  |--------------------|
  |  C    |  6   |  6  |
  ----------------------
```

Is it possible in Python using Pandas or any other module?

---

Comment: Do you need merge duplicated values?

Comment: yes, it is possible. Please look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how to ask a question with a high chance of being answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
df['Sum']=df.groupby('Type').transform('sum')
df.loc[df[['Type','Sum']].duplicated(),['Type','Sum']]=''
print(df)
```

---

```
   Type     Val Sum
0    A        1   3
1             2    
2    B        3  12
3             4    
4             5    
5    C        6   6
```

P.s: you can also add this as index:

```
df=df.set_index(['Type','Sum']) #export to excel without index=False
```

---

[image]

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For merged first 2 levels is possible set all 3 columns to `MultiIndex` - only order of columns is different:

```
#specify column name after groupby
df['Sum'] = df.groupby('Type')['Val'].transform('sum')

df = df.set_index(['Type','Sum', 'Val'])
df.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

But in my opinion the best is working with duplicated values:

```
df['Sum'] = df.groupby('Type')['Val'].transform('sum')
print (df)

  Type  Val  Sum
0    A    1    3
1    A    2    3
2    B    3   12
3    B    4   12
4    B    5   12
5    C    6    6

df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: giving me same results :(

Comment: So if empty string it merge?

Comment: Yes, try exporting to excel, its giving me exact same excel. :)

Comment: merging required

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['A', 'A','B','B','B','C'], 'Val': [1,2 ,3,4,5,6]})

df_result = df.merge(df.groupby(by='Type', as_index=False).agg({'Val':'sum'}).rename(columns={'Val':'Sum'}), on = 'Type')
```

which gives the output as

```
print(df_result)
  Type  Val  Sum
0    A    1    3
1    A    2    3
2    B    3   12
3    B    4   12
4    B    5   12
5    C    6    6
```

Is this what you are looking for?